# how to make one fileupload mentadory and other not in Struts2

Tags: struts2

Hi i have two file upload field in my Struts2 jsp i want to have the first field to be mendatory and the second may be empty. How could i do this using fileupload interceptor

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing the validation on client side or server side?

Comment: write your own validation method and let file2 nullable.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to do following - Write 2 methods in struts 2 Action class

validate() - this method will be called on upload button click call javascript function and submit Ajax request to Struts 2 Action, and validate() method of this Action will just check weather user has browsed atleast one file and will return true or false value based on this.

execute() - if validation() method returns true then only submit the form (submit form through javascript), so that it will call execute() method and perform file upload logic here.